# Split values of a field with multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mustache

Im currently working on an ecommerce website and i am having trouble on rendering the report on my page.

here is my node server.js

```
app.get('/adminReport', function (req,res){
var transaction = []
        mongoDb.collection('transactions').find().toArray(function(err,results) 
        {
            transaction =results
        //console.log(results);
            return res.render('adminReport.html', {
            transactions: transaction
            });
        });
});
```

here is my code on HTML

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Transaction ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>Time Ordered</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Purchase Option(Pick-up or Delivery)</th>
        <th>Payment Method</th>
        <th>Item Ordered</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
        {{#transactions}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{_id}}</td>
        <td>{{lastName}}, {{firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{userId}}</td>

        <td>{{timeOrdered}}</td>
        <td>{{jobTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{address}} , {{city}}, {{province}}, {{zip}}</td>
        <td>{{email}}</td>
        <td>{{contactNo}}</td>
        <td>{{purchaseOpt}}</td>
        <td>{{paymentMethod}}</td>
        <td>
                <table>
                    <th>Transaction ID</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
             <!-- item purchased -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{cartId}}</td>
                        <td>{{itemName}}</td>
                        <td>{{quantity}}</td>
                        <td>₱{{price}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        <td>{{status}}</td>

    </tr> {{/transactions}}
```

here is the result in chromes view-source

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Transaction ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>Time Ordered</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Purchase Option(Pick-up or Delivery)</th>
        <th>Payment Method</th>
        <th>Item Ordered</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>5c9711730d8f1c2287f5a439</td>
        <td>Jordan, Micheal</td>
        <td>12341</td>

        <td>Sunday 24 Mar 1:11 PM</td>
        <td>Programmer</td>
        <td>123 St. Atlanta , Baguio, Kadabra, 1500</td>
        <td>micheal@tesing.com</td>
        <td>95057435</td>
        <td>pickUp</td>
        <td>cash</td>
        <td>
                <table>
                    <th>Transaction ID</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
            <!-- item purchased -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>5c95cb8f36d0c71f05ddf9de,5c95d4b6d82a782747e929a3</td>
                        <td>Bag,Shirt</td>
                        <td>2,1</td>
                        <td>₱62,20</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        <td></td>

    </tr> 

</tbody>
```

i want to split the Bag and shirt on different `<td>`.

I am using mongoDB as my database and is it possible to split the value if only a certain field has multiple value?

```
    firstName: 'Micheal',
    lastName: 'Jordan',
    kinId: '12341',
    country: 'Deployed',
    contactNo: '95057435',
    email: 'micheal@tesing.com',
    jobTitle: 'Programmer',
    address: '123 St. Atlanta',
    province: 'Kadabra',
    city: 'Baguio',
    zip: '1500',
    purchaseOpt: 'pickUp',
    paymentMethod: 'cash',
    timeOrdered: 'Sunday 24 Mar 1:11 PM',
    cartId: [ '5c95cb8f36d0c71f05ddf9de', '5c95d4b6d82a782747e929a3' ],
    itemName: [ 'Bag', 'Shirt' ],
    quantity: [ '2', '1' ],
    price: [ '62', '20' ] } ]
```

For this matter the cartId,itemName,quantity,price are the only fields with multiple value, is it possible to render it separately on my HTML page like Bag and shirt on different `<td>`.

Comment: Your schema could do with some work. Instead of having different arrays in the document, you should instead have a **single** array of objects. i.e `items: [{ _id: '5c95cb8f36d0c71f05ddf9de', name: 'Bag', quantity: 2, price: 62 }, { _id: '5c95d4b6d82a782747e929a3', name: 'Shirt', quantity: 1, price: 20 }]`. That basically makes things easier than looping by index in processing, and later you will find you don't run into a problem with multi-key indexes in MongoDB, that you current design is prone to.

Comment: thanks for this Neil, i'll be using this idea, thanks a lot :)

Comment: With a little digging you basically need to. Either by having that structure in the database or by running a loop over the arrays in the document at present to coerce them into that form. Apparantly mustache lacks any way to "dynamically" refer to an array element by it's index position. This means you need your data in that sort of form in order to process in your template the way you want. But it makes the most sense to simply store it in that database that way in the first place. For various other reasons as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the values of `itemName`, `cartId`, etc., in the same way you're looping through your transactions array.

So, instead of:

```
<td>{{itemName}}</td>
```

Try something like:

```
{{#itemName}}
  <td>{{itemName}}</td>
{{/itemName}}
```

See the [mustache docs](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) at the section titled "Non-Empty Lists".

Comment: The main problem as I saw it was that the actual issue is how to "loop" something like `cartId`, and then use the *current array index* in order to get the same matching position item from each of the other arrays in the "transaction". AFAIK the mustache philosophy is "minimal logic", and as such there is no such *dynamic variable* access. What you need to do is restructure the data **first**. Hence why it would be far better to simply store the data in MongoDB just how you want to use it in the template. Then you are just "looping" *sub-items* from the transaction within the template

Comment: jknotek thanks for the help, i tried this one but the outcome is still the same, but i gained new knowledge about mustache though, thank you :)